# Looking for a portfolio module?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module

I am looking for a specific module for Joomla, open source or paid does not matter, most importantly it has the options I need.

What I am looking for is a portfolio module where each photographer can have their own subpage with their own art (photos and movies).

The main page should be a page where there is a photo of the photographer and the opportunity to add a little text about the photographer and his work.

The subpages (each photographer's main page) must be a main page with a text and a photo of the photographer, and then all his photo galleries or movie sets must be listed.

So basically a module that can create a huge portfolio with many subpages contains photo sets and movies.
Does anyone know a good module that can fit this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any ready made multi-user portfolio extension for Joomla and you may need a combination of extensions together with the core Joomla features to achieve all the functionality you require.

If you want photographers to be able to manage photo albums from the front-end of the website, this limits your choices quite a bit as there are only a few gallery extensions with front-end management features. Here are some examples I have used:

- [Ignite Gallery](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ignite-gallery) (paid)
- [Balbooa Joomla Gallery](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/6gallery) (paid)
- [JoomGallery](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/joomgallery) (free)

You can find others in the [Joomla Extensions Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org).

You may need an extension to restrict users to specific folders such as:

- [KL My Media](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/kl-my-media) (Paid)
- [RSFiles!](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rsfiles) (Paid)

You may be able to use one of the social / community extensions which usually seem to include shared photo albums but these may be overkill for what you need:

- [EasySocial](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easysocial) (Paid)
- [JomSocial](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jomsocial) (Paid)
- [Community Builder](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/community-builder) (Basics are Free)
- [Sociable](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sociable) (Paid)